# grep: write error: Broken pipe with subprocess

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

I get couple of grep:write errors when I run this code. 
What am I missing?

This is only part of it:

```
     while d <= datetime.datetime(year, month, daysInMonth[month]):
        day = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        print day
        results = [day]
        first=subprocess.Popen("grep -Eliw 'Algeria|Bahrain' "+ monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt | grep -Eliw 'Protest|protesters' "+ monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
        output1=first.communicate()[0]
        d += delta
        day = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        second=subprocess.Popen("grep -Eliw 'Algeria|Bahrain' "+ monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt | grep -Eliw 'Protest|protesters' "+ monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt", shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
        output2=second.communicate()[0]
        articleList = (output1.split('\n'))
        articleList2 = (output2.split('\n'))
        results.append( len(articleList)+len(articleList2))
        w.writerow(tuple(results))
        d += delta
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. When you give filename arguments to `grep` it does't read from stdin, so why are you piping the output of one grep process to the second one?

Comment: I am filtering the files that contain the keyword Algeria OR Bahrain and protests OR protests. It's actually a lil more complicated I just simplified it for this question. I want to get all the files that contain one of the keywords in list1 and one of the keywords in list2

Comment: Any particular reason for not using Python's regular expression library, `re`? It would save you calling out to grep.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do

```
A | B
```

in a shell, process A's output is piped into process B as input. If process B shuts down before reading all of process A's output (e.g. because it found what it was looking for, which is the function of the `-l` option), then process A may complain that its output pipe was prematurely closed.

These errors are basically harmless, and you can work around them by redirecting `stderr` in the subprocesses to `/dev/null`.

A better approach, though, may simply be to use Python's powerful regex capabilities to read the files:

```
def fileContains(fn, pat):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search(pat, line):
                return True
    return False

first = []
for file in glob.glob(monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt"):
    if fileContains(file, 'Algeria|Bahrain') and fileContains(file, 'Protest|protesters'):
        file.append(first)
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the files matching two patterns, the command structure should be:

```
grep -l pattern1 $(grep -l pattern2 files)
```

`$(command)` substitutes the output of the command into the command line.

So your script should be:

```
first=subprocess.Popen("grep -Eliw 'Algeria|Bahrain' $("+ grep -Eliw 'Protest|protesters' "+ monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt)", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
```

and similarly for `second`

Comment: It didn't work for me. Can you explain though why I get broken pipe in some cases and some cases I don't. What does the error mean?

Comment: Broken pipe means that the command tried to write to the pipe, but the read end was closed. I don't think it should happen when you use `first.communicate()`, since that reads until EOF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for whole words, you could use the `count()` member function;

```
# assuming names is a list of filenames
for fn in names:
    with open(fn) as infile:
        text = infile.read().lower()
    # remove puntuation
    text = text.replace(',', '')
    text = text.replace('.', '')
    words = text.split()
    print "Algeria:", words.count('algeria')
    print "Bahrain:", words.count('bahrain')
    print "protesters:", words.count('protesters')
    print "protest:", words.count('protest')
```

If you want more powerful filtering, use `re`.

Answer (score 0):

Add stderr args in the Popen function based on the python version the stderr value will change. This will support if the python version is less than 3

first=subprocess.Popen("grep -Eliw 'Algeria|Bahrain' "+ monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt | grep -Eliw 'Protest|protesters' "+ monthDir +"/"+day+"*.txt", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33480206)